# Flask route rule as function args

Tags: python, flask

I want to specify an arbitrary number of arguments to a route in the form of a path: `/arg/arg2/arg3/etc`.  I can't figure out how to catch all these "sub-routes" under a route in a single function.  How can I make this work?

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask("Example")

@app.route("/test/<command>/*")
def test(command=None, *args):
    return "{0}: {1}".format(command, args)

app.run()
```

Intended behavior is:

- `/test/say` -> `say: ()`
- `/test/say/` -> `say: ()`
- `/test/say/hello` -> `say: ("hello",)`
- `/test/say/hello/to/you` -> `say: ("hello", "to", "you")`

Comment: Not quite what you're after, but there's an example of writing a custom URL converter here (https://exploreflask.com/views.html#url-converters) that could probably be adapted to something that'd work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can accept multiple args, the way you'd like to.

One way to do this, is to define multiple routes.

```
@app.route('/test/<command>')
@app.route('/test/<command>/<arg1>')
@app.route('/test/<command>/<arg1>/<arg2>')
def test(command=None, arg1=None, arg2=None):
    a = [arg1, arg2]
    # Remove any args that are None
    args = [arg for arg in a if arg is not None]
    if command == "say":
        return ' '.join(args)
    else:
        return "Unknown Command"
```

`http://127.0.0.1/test/say/hello/` should return `hello`

`http://127.0.0.1/test/say/hello/there` should return `hello there`

Another way to do this is to use `path`:

```
@app.route('/test/<command>/<path:path>')
def test(command, path):
    args = path.split('/')
    return " ".join(args)
```

If you use this, then if you go to `http://127.0.0.1/test/say/hello/there`.

Then `path` will be set to the value `hello/there`. This is why we split it.

Answer (score 2):

To completely cover the intended behaviour the solution is:

```
@app.route("/test/<command>") 
@app.route("/test/<command>/")
@app.route("/test/<command>/<path:args>") 
def test(command="", args=""):                                                  
    if args:
        args = tuple(args.split("/"))
    else:
        args = tuple() 

    return "{0}: {1}".format(command, args)
```